# Move spam detected mails to users "Spam" subdirectory

Tags: email, spam-prevention, maildir

My mailserver setup is based on [Das Postfix Buch](http://www.postfixbuch.de/) ( from an good german IT consultant agency ) and the [ISPmail Tutorials](http://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze). In short I use virtuals ( maildir ) with MySQL config backend and `amavisd-new` ( v2.7 ) on Debian Squeeze. Mails are stored in the following directory pattern: `/var/vmail/%d/%u`. For now spam detected emails will be stored within `/var/vmail/quarantaine`.

I like to store spam detected emails within the correct mailbox directory ( `/var/vmail/%d/%u/.Spam` ). But how to do this? Amavisd-new does not support variables in `*-destiny`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let Amavisd-new/spamassassin insert the headers ("X-Spam-Flag") into the spam-mails.

Then use the Sieve filter in dovecot to move the marked mails into your spam folder (you can find an [example in the dovecot wiki](http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Sieve#SpamAssassin.2BAC8-Amavis_tagged_mail_filtering))

Comment: Thank you, rmweiss. Sadly that there are no other options...

Comment: The link above was for dovecot v1. Here the updated link for dovecot v2: [Pigeonhole Sieve examples](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Examples#Direct_filtering_using_message_header)